# Ending the session in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP login page for a particular application with a session. When I sign out, I want to redirect it to my login page and end my session. So that when the person using the application presses the back button, my earlier transactions aren't seen. I don't want to disable by back button.
I am new to JSP. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: you can use this [link] (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072937/java-web-development/solving-the-logout-problem-properly-and-elegantly.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are already validating that a certain session variable exists in your protected pages.  So basically to log the user out you just need to invalidate the session and do a server-side redirect:

```
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("loginform_url");
return;
```

But you need to also set cache-control headers on your protected pages to prevent the browser from caching the protected pages. Otherwise, the user could go to those pages again and see the cached version despite being logged out.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Comment: Or use a filter that validates if there's a logged user and has authorized access to these views.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my demo logout page looks:

```
<h2> You have logged out. </h2>
<h2>To login again</h2> <a href="Login.jsp"><b>Login</b></a>
<%if(session!=null) { 
session.invalidate();   
session.removeAttribute("user");
} %>
```

But this doesn't seem to help!